# How to make the visible color of cesium transparent

Tags: javascript, glsl, cesiumjs

I have made a visual field with cesium, but I cannot make the color transparent to see the specific information of the buildings behind. May I ask if there is any method to make the color transparent?

Here's my analysis:

[image]

Here is the code I set the color:

```
fsSource += 
if(visibility < 1.0){
   //gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
   gl_FragColor = vec4(244.0 / 256.0, 96.0 / 256.0, 108.0 / 256.0, 0.2); 
}else{ 
   //gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5);
   gl_FragColor = vec4(25.0 / 256.0, 202.0 / 256.0, 173.0 / 256.0, 0.2);
}
//gl_FragColor.rgb *= visibility; 
//gl_FragColor.rgb *= 1.0;
};
```

Comment: Can you show some Cesium code in addition to the GLSL?  I see you have a `gl_FragColor.a` of `0.2`, but that won't do anything unless alpha-blending is enabled from the JavaScript side.

Comment: Also what platform/driver is this?  I asked because there is a [known issue with blending](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/8101) that is specific to Linux + NVIDIA + certain driver versions.

Comment: I use Windows+Chrome+NVIDIA Quadro P2000 431.40.

Comment: I also set the alpha-blending parameters in shadowmap.Here is the code:

Comment: 'function createRenderState(colorMask, bias) {
        return RenderState.fromCache({
            depthMask : true,
            blending : {
                enabled : true,
                functionSourceRgb : WebGLConstants.SRC_COLOR,
                functionSourceAlpha : WebGLConstants.SRC_ALPHA,
                functionDestinationRgb : WebGLConstants.ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR,
                functionDestinationAlpha : WebGLConstants.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA
            }
        });
    }'

Comment: The result picture is as follows:[![2.png](https://i.postimg.cc/rwMJBw5S/2.png)](https://postimg.cc/JGYZJm6n)